# Git workflow for small changes

Tags: php, git, version-control

I'm a single developer looking for a viable workflow with Git in my personal local projects. I already understood the concepts and basic commands of Git, but I'm new to the VCS concepts.

I use VSCode, Git and Laragon locally. Let's say I cloned the Laravel repo, for a new project and created a branch to make the inicial changes. Is that the corret approach? I want to modify code and test until I consider that is time to make a commit. How can I do that if for every change is necessary to make a commit to save the changes to the files and then make a test or show in browser?

Maybe I'm having a missconception on the VCS purposes. Any help is useful.

Comment: I think you do have a major misconception. It is not necessary to make commits to change the files. You can change and use the files just like any other files on your computer, VCS doesn't have anything to do with that. You'd make a commit only when you want to save your work to the version control.

Comment: I've never heard about Laragon before and the authors seem to think their product is too awesome to care explaining what it is. Is that the tool that's forcing you to commit changes just to run the code through a browser?

Comment: @GuyIncognito, when I change code and save the file in VSCode with Git enable, the file receive a "tag" of modified file, ok, but the file is not physically modified. I have to commit and then test. It's obviously a lame question, feel free to help.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, Laragon it's just like mamp, xampp, wamp, etc, and no, it's not the tool. Maybe it's the VSCode, I'm using the Git plugin.

Comment: If you save a file and the file is not changed on disk then there's something wrong in your setup. I suggest you remove all tools from the equation and start trying things one by one until you determine which tool is causing the issue.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, thank you, I'll look for it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are the sole developer of the project. You can create two more branches like `develop` and `test`. You can keep your `develop` branch as your daily commit branch, this way your code will be secure in case of any machine failure and you can also keep of track what changes you made in case you need them later.

Once you are satisfied with your code in the `develop` branch, you can merge it into the `test` branch. After doing some tests and when you feel like that this code is ready to be brought to production then merge it into the `master` branch. `master` branch is usually considered as a production branch.